# Text gets stuck on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have an 2 arrays one contains html tags the other contains css properties

Thats not really important just background info

I have a code that is triggered when a user clicks on my canvas element now the purpose of this code is to determine what the *terminal*(aka the canvas) supports

If the canvas only supports HTML then the first code block is triggered if the *terminal* supports both HTML and CSS then the second code block is triggered

The first code block selects a random tag from the htmltags array and then displays it where the user clicked on the canvas

The second code block which supports HTML and CSS take the 2 arrays and combines them and selects a random tag or property from the new array and displays it where the user clicked

Now before I added the second code block it was functioning properly but once I added in the second code block it seems that both code blocks are sticking at the 2nd tag

For Example
Click 1: `<br>`
Click 2: `<i>`
Click 3-infinite: `<i>`

Here is my code I have looked at this for 2 hours trying to fix it I leave it to stack now

```js
function writeMessage(canvas, message, x, y) {
    var terminal = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ClearCanvas();
    terminal.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
    terminal.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,1)";
    terminal.textAlign = "center";
    terminal.fillText(message, x, y);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("terminalCanvas");
var terminal = canvas.getContext("2d");
fitToContainer(canvas);

terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
terminal.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
terminal.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
terminal.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,1)";
terminal.textAlign = "center";
terminal.fillText("Coding Idle Terminal", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

function WriteToCanvas() {
    if (Game.Terminal.HTMLSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.CSSSupport == 0) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 122) + 1;
        var tag = htmltags[rand];

        Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.clicksTotal += 1;

        $('#terminalCanvas').click(function(evt) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
            var message = tag;
            writeMessage(canvas, message, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
        });
    } else if (Game.Terminal.HTMLSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.CSSSupport == 1) {
        var tagList = htmltags.concat(csstags);
        var tagListLength = tagList.length;
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tagListLength) + 1;
        var tagg = tagList[rand];

        Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.clicksTotal += 1;

        $('#terminalCanvas').click(function(evt) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
            var message = tagg;
            writeMessage(canvas, message, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
        });
    }
}

function ClearCanvas() {
    terminal.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
    terminal.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function fitToContainer(canvas) {
    canvas.style.width = '100%';
    canvas.style.height = '100%';

    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
}

WriteToCanvas();
```

Comment: Didnt solve the issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the issue, I've done a fiddle with your code, i've added extra declaration (that you didn't include). https://jsfiddle.net/rv384g8p/  I've removed the +1 in rand, that will get your data outside the array range. If you call WriteToCanvas() only one time, you will only get one "tag" or "tagg" variable. And the click event listener will always use it.

Comment: But how could it change the text from <br> to <i> on click 2, if tag didn't change ?

Comment: Unless you call WriteToCanvas many times, and you keep adding click event listener over and over and over... but the ClearCanvas() hide the previous click, even if the code is executed.

Comment: The answer I submitted works fine `WriteToCanvas()` is called every time user clicks the canvas

Comment: I've checked in my debugger your code, since WriteToCanvas is inside a click event on the canvas, you are adding click event every time you click. On initialization you have 1 click listener. On first click you add the call to writeMessage. Second click will add another click event that call writeMessage, Third click, 4 click listener and so on... It could be very funny if you remove the ClearCanvas() because you will add 1 random tag, 2 random tags, 3 random tags, etc...

Comment: yikes hmmm it appears your right

Comment: I guess, I would just add one click event listener with the evt argument, and put all the logic if condition, checking the state of the game, using random(), generating the message and writing it inside that function.

Comment: Can't do that because the click function relies on the rand tag to be passed into it each call hmm ima go to bed maybe someone will find a solution by morning nite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue

because `eventListenerExist` was a global variable once the first code block set the event listener the second code block couldnt reset the listener with the updated tags so my solution was to check for clicks every call instead of adding an event listener here is my updated code for people who visit the question in the future

```js
function writeMessage(canvas, message,x,y) {
        var terminal = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ClearCanvas();
        terminal.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
        terminal.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,1)";
        terminal.textAlign = "center";
        terminal.fillText(message, x, y);
}
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("terminalCanvas");
var terminal = canvas.getContext("2d");

terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
terminal.fillRect(0,0,150,200);

function WriteToCanvas(){
    if(Game.Terminal.HTMLSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.CSSSupport == 0){ 
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 122) + 1;
        var tag = htmltags[rand];

        Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.clicksTotal += 1;

        $('#terminalCanvas').click(function(evt){
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
            var message = tag;
            writeMessage(canvas, message,mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
        });
    }else if(Game.Terminal.HTMLSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.CSSSupport == 1){
        var tagList = htmltags.concat(csstags);
        var tagListLength = tagList.length;
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tagListLength) + 1;
        var tagg = tagList[rand];

        Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement;
        Game.Player.clicksTotal += 1;

        $('#terminalCanvas').click(function(evt){
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
            var message = tagg;
            writeMessage(canvas, message,mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
        });
    }
}

function ClearCanvas(){
    terminal.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
    terminal.fillRect(0,0,150,200);
}

WriteToCanvas();
```